# python cmd module exit shortcut

Tags: python, python-cmd

Using python `cmd` module, I would like to be able to quit the command line application using Ctrl+D. However, default behavior prints `^D` instead of quitting the application.

[Reading the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html), I can't seem to find a way to do it. Any hints ?

Answer (score 3):

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html):

> An end-of-file on input is passed back as the string 'EOF'.

Which means that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is dispatched to the `do_EOF()` method. So to give a way to exit your interpreter, make sure to implement `do_EOF()` and have it return `True`:

```
def do_EOF(self, line):
    return True
```

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. When I type `Ctrl+D` it just prints `^D`. Using `Ctrl+C` exits the application, but without calling do_EOF. Any hints ?

Comment: @Overdrivr: Have you overriden any of `Cmd`'s methods? If yes, you'd need to post the relevant code; if not, `Ctrl+D` should work after you add the above `do_EOF` method to your `Cmd` subclass (I've just tested it myself and it works).

Comment: Good point, hitting Ctrl+D should raise a KeyboardInterrupt or SystemExit exception is this correct ?

Comment: @Overdrivr: `EOFError`, I guess. But this is catched and handled by `cmd` anyway (by dispatching to `do_EOF()`).